# How to get descriptions of imported Google maps landmarks?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Briefly: I created a map in Mymaps, saving places (click on a landmark, "save to.."), I customized icons and saved. [This](http://goo.gl/maps/EoCN) is my map. Then I exported the kml file and imported it in a [web page](http://www.tenutalasantissima.com/en/siena-e-la-toscana/) using [GeoXML V3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/) and Google Maps API v3 with javasctipt, in order to have a nice sidebar. As you can see, clicking on my landmarks in GMaps, I can get the address, "More info", the website and a description and conversely in my web page all this informations are not available.
Is used the option "clickable:true". I don't understand if the problem is solvable using some options in Google Maps API or in the parser GeoXML v3.
Some one can help me?
Thank you!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var Tenuta=new google.maps.LatLng(43.246266,11.295608);
        var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.246266,11.295608),zoom: 10,mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,clickableLabels:true});


        ...


        var base = "../../content/siena/map/example.kml"
        var path = base;

        var myParser = new GeoXml("myParser", map, path, {nozoom:true, titlestyle: 'id="infowindowsTitle" ',sidebarid: "the_side_bar",allfoldersopen:true,iwwidth:1, iwheight:1});

        myParser.parse("Point of interest next to Tenuta la Santissima");


</script>
```

Comment: I clicked on your website link, and it looks like it's working to me. Did you get it fixed? If so, could you answer your own question? Someone else might benefit from your solution! (I'd really like to know, too!)

Comment: I didn't found a solution for this. I think that Google doesn't provide this functionality if you use a KML. Maybe using the API for Google Places you can achieve this. What you see when you click an icon in the map or in the sidebar is an html with links created by me!

Comment: can you provide the .kml file and let us know what information are you trying to import and what is happening ?

Comment: strange world we're living in

Answer (score 0):

You can use DomParser to read KML by your code.
Please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/53183890/2360310.