# Display kml using input box in html and displaying it on gmaps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I had got a `kml file` from google earth.

I would like to pass it into a input box and then, the attributes such as line or maker or polygon which is plotted in `kml file` are to be displayed on google maps.

I didn't find any useful information regarding this in internet.

Can anyone give me the proper idea how to parse `kml file` using html input box and then displaying it on map?

Comment: Why do you want to parse it in order to display it on a map?  To display it, you just create a google.maps.KmlLayer and pass in the URL of the KML and the map on which you want it displayed.  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kml

Comment: Sorry I don't need to parse it. The link you suggested has "var src " which load the required kml file which is hosted in online .But my requirement is client side .Where the user load his own kml file and when he submit it ,the map should display the kml.

Comment: With google maps, I'm pretty sure the KML has to be hosted somewhere. you might check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032505/read-out-kml-file-with-javascript